# Firebase cannot save any data

Tags: java, firebase

I'm trying to just do a simple test in firebase and save a hashmap that contains a string, and a boolean, but I cannot save the data, it never gets pushed.
http://hastebin.com/qucocuqexe.cs

Answer (score 6):

Firebase unloads all work onto background threads. When running on the JVM, events are fired on a separate thread, not on the main thread. It's likely that your simple test application is finishing before any background threads could actually do any work.

You'll need to use synchronization primitives (e.g. semaphores) to make sure that Firebase could actually finish the requested operation. Try waiting for the `setValue(...)` to complete with something like:

```
public static Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://shs-newspaper.firebaseio.com//").child("news");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
    Map<String, Boolean> test = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    test.put("Test", true);
    ref.setValue(test, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(FirebaseError error, Firebase ref) {
            semaphore.release();
        }
    });
    ref.setValue(test);
    semaphore.acquire();
}
```